# Discord.py wait_for reply in dm from two users

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot where it will send a dm to two users (one author and the other mentioned) and waits for a response, which then sends it back to the server. The bot is able to send dm and it does timeout correctly but even if both users respond to the dm, it does not work properly.

```
users = [user1id, user2id]
    for user in users:
        await user.send(f'List {rounds} character(s)')

    try:
        user1msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check = lambda x: x.channel ==  user1id.dm_channel and x.author == user1id, timeout=5)
        user2msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check = lambda x: x.channel == user2id.dm_channel and x.author == user2id, timeout=5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('One or both users did not respond in time.')
    else:
        await ctx.send(user1msg.content)
        await ctx.send(user2msg.content)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: Without doing a try block, this works fine and both messages will be sent after each user has sent.

Comment: "but even if both users respond" Are you sure? Try adding `print(user1msg.content, user2msg.content)` and checking it was actually working. Also note that the timeout was set to 5 seconds, which is probably really low. Are you sure that the error text in the except is actually being executed (add print statement before trying to send a message)?

Comment: The timeout was set for testing purposes, they do both work without the try loop. The error is being executed because after the 5 seconds (normally it would be 45), the message gets sent saying "One or both users did not respond in time".

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by utilizing the `asyncio.gather` function (Although I was not able to get it to be in a try block, so I am unable to catch the `asyncio.TimeoutError`.)

```
user1msg, user2msg = await asyncio.gather(    
    bot.wait_for('message', check = lambda x: x.channel == user1id.dm_channel and x.author == user1id, timeout=45),
    bot.wait_for('message', check = lambda x: x.channel == user2id.dm_channel and x.author == user2id, timeout=45))
    
    await ctx.send(f'user1: {user1msg.content}\nuser2: {user2msg.content}')
```

This will wait until both users have responded and then it will send their messages back to where the command was used.

If anyone can help me figure out how to use this in a try block, I will appreciate it but it is not needed. The problem that occurs is that when it is in a try block, it will only dm the first user, the first user has to respond then it will send a dm to the second user - which is what I do not want. Want it to happen concurrently

Comment: "happen concurrently" then yes, asyncio gather would be something you would want here. You can also make a second coroutine that sort of links between the two of them something like this: `async def waitfor(user1id: int):`; `try:`; `await bot.wait_for(...)`; `except asyncio.TimeoutError` and gathering that.